# Rails active_link_to img button CSS is showing the file name instead of img

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble with the active_link_to active state for my home button. But, I'm sure one solution will help me fix all future img css buttons to work correctly. The link to the button is showing /index.1 for current_user instead of the house img icon that I styled it with. My code is below

html

```
<li class="nav-item">
            <%= active_link_to home_path(current_user), class_active: 'nav-link home-icon-btn active', :class_inactive => 'nav-link', active: :exclusive %>
          </li>
```

css

```
.home-icon-btn {
  background:url('white-home-btn-state-1.png') no-repeat;
  cursor:pointer;
  border:none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.home-icon-btn:hover {
  background: url('white-home-btn-state-2.png') no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.active {
  border-bottom: 3px white solid;
}
```

This is just one of 6 buttons that I will use on the navigation bar. How do you properly display the image on the link?..The active state border-bottom is working btw.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I changed the link format to this: <%= active_link_to '', profile_path, class_active: 'nav-link home-icon-btn active', :class_inactive => 'nav-link', active: :exclusive %>